# How can I set an alias for a command in bash that works in any folder?

Tags: macos, bash, path, alias

So, I have created a bash_profile and set the aliases, but they just work in my home folder (cd/). Is there a way where I can use this aliases whenever I am in?
I am using the Bash in MAC OS X.

Thanks brothers.

EDIT:

It appears these aliases are for cd commands to folders in the home folder or for scripts in the home folder. For example:

```
alias jobs2015='cd Documents/erickjones/_Aotopo/_jobs/2015
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense as the `alias` is a setting of the shell process and that shell process remains stable regardless of the current directory.  You are missing something vital from your question; please post the output from a shell session showing your issue.

Comment: I created an alias like this:

$ nano .bash_profile

Then this opened the bash profile and I created the shortcuts to folders:

alias jobs2015='cd Documents/erickjones/_Aotopo/_jobs/2015'

This works since I am in the home folder. Naturally. I want to know how can I go home and then hit those folders.

Thank you very much.

Comment: ... more confusion.  Voting to close.

Comment: Vote to close? Oh god. Thank you, I have already received a good quality answer. Sorry if I didn't ask perfect.

Comment: Very very far from perfect I'm afraid.  You gave little to no clue as to what the issue was and rghome did well to figure it out.

Comment: It was confusing, but I figured out what he wanted. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your aliases are either for `cd` commands to folders in your home folder or to run scripts that are in your home folder.

Your options are:

1. Prefix the command or cd-directories by `$HOME/` when you define the aliases.
2. For commands, include the `HOME` folder (or other folder where your scripts are) in the PATH.
3. For `cd`, include the `HOME` folder in the `CDPATH` variable.

`PATH` is the list of folders that are searched to find a command that you are executed. YOu can add directories to it, but be careful not to delete existing ones. See here: [PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path)

`CDPATH` is a list of folders where cd will look for the folder to search. See here [CDPATH](http://swarm.cs.pub.ro/~razvan/blog/some-bash-tricks-cdpath-and-inputrc/)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is exactly what I was searching for.